# Count the days between events mysql

Tags: mysql

```
       name          date
|A BADGE TOO FAR| 1997-03-15|
|A BADGE TOO FAR| 1997-03-22|
|A BEAT SO FAR  | 2010-11-19|
|A BEAT SO FAR  | 2011-01-11|
|A BEAT SO FAR  | 2012-03-04|
|A BEAT SO FAR  | 2012-03-29|
```

I have a data table like the sample above and I need to count the days between the dates

Comment: Could you share the output you expect to get for this sample? It would make the question easier to answer.

Comment: DATEDIFF() didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to hold the date from the previous row in a session variable, and use the [DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function as @eightShirt commented.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(date, @d), @d:=date
FROM mytable
ORDER BY date;
```

Make sure you order by `date` to get the rows in the right order. Without explicitly ordering a query, there's no guarantee the rows will be processed in any particular order. In practice, it's typically by index order, for whichever index the query uses, but that's up to the optimizer.

SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3f413/2